# Projective limit of compact spaces

Tags: general-topology

I'm studying projective limits and I suddenly come up with this question: is the projective limit of compact sets remains compact?

Well, although I found a proof via  Tychonoff theorem, I construct a counterexample of this and I wonder if it's right..

Consider $X_i$ is the set containing $1,2,...,i$, each $X_i$ equipped with discrete topology therefore compact, and define the map $$f_{ij}:X_i\to X_j(i>j)$$ by sending all integers bigger than $j$ to $j$ while keep others fixed.  Obviously these maps are continuous, and form a projective system, but the projective limit is not compact, as every single element is open in the limit $\mathbb{N}$.

I don't know where it goes wrong but it contradicts to a theorem on the textbook...

Comment: You are wrong in the assumption that the limit is the discrete $\mathbb{N}$. It is not.

Comment: The limit isn't $\mathbb{N}$. You haven't proven this and it isn't true! What element of $\mathbb{N}$ corresponds to the choice of $i \in X_i$?

Comment: Also, I think you might be confusing direct limit with projective (inverse) limit. You claim that the system is projective (inverse) but morphism indexation is incorrect. It should be $f_{ij}:X_j\to X_i$. Which then makes sense why you think $\mathbb{N}$ is the limit.

Comment: Ah yeah you are right, the limit should contains another one point which makes it compact. Thank you all for your comments!